# Configure a component in ASP.Net 5

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core

There are differents ways to configure a component in ASP.Net 5 :

- the AddXXX method, used for adding services,
- the ConfigureXXX method, used for configuring the options,
- the UseXXX method, use to register a middleware into the pipeline.

The ConfigureXXX() method has the responsability to configure a component or a subcomponent :

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L12

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureAuthorization(
    [NotNull] this IServiceCollection services, 
    [NotNull] Action<AuthorizationOptions> configure)
{
    return services.Configure(configure);
}
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L50

```
public static void ConfigureMvc(
    [NotNull] this IServiceCollection services,
    [NotNull] Action<MvcOptions> setupAction)
{
    services.Configure(setupAction);
}
```

But sometimes the ConfigureXXX is a bit more complex : 
https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies/CookieServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L31

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureCookieAuthentication(
    [NotNull] this IServiceCollection services, 
    [NotNull] IConfiguration config, 
    string optionsName)
{
    return services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(config, optionsName);
}
```

Why some existings components are more "configurables" than others ?

As a component writer, what should I practice?

Another related question :
AddXXX & UseXXX sometimes allows to configure the component : 
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L32

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddMvcCore(
    [NotNull] this IServiceCollection services,
    [NotNull] Action<MvcOptions> setupAction)
{
    ConfigureDefaultServices(services);
    AddMvcCoreServices(services);
    services.Configure(setupAction);
    return new MvcBuilder() { Services = services, };
}
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuth/OAuthAuthenticationExtensions.cs#L22

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseOAuthAuthentication(
    [NotNull] this IApplicationBuilder app, 
    [NotNull] string authenticationScheme, 
    Action<OAuthAuthenticationOptions> configureOptions = null)
{
    return app.UseMiddleware<OAuthAuthenticationMiddleware<OAuthAuthenticationOptions>>(
    // [...]
}
```

Basically, what is the sementic difference between configuring the options with the three differents methods ? Especially when it is available on the same component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with options and any component that's using the IOptions service, the idea was to make it easy to configure options at any point in the stack (Add, Use, Configure) they are all valid, but order does matter.

The general pattern we've been using is generally taking `Action<YourOptions>` wherever it might seem useful.